# Recently bought computer blocks IP addresses from Adobe

Tags: windows-10, adobe, config, ip-blocking

To make it short:

I bought a computer and I suspect that the person using it was ***cracking*** licenses from Adobe, e.g. Photoshop or something, I've heard that in order to do that correctly you need to *block some IP addresses from Adobe* in order for the program to not realize that it's being used without a license. I now do want to use my *bought Adobe programs*, would any of you be kind and show **direct me to the config/system file** that includes/**excludes specific IP addresses from Adobe**? I'm on a **Windows 10** machine (had a few partitions when I got it, so I suspect there might have been some dual-booting going on). Anything that might help me with this issue would be amazing, thank you very much!

PS: If there's a way to reset the entire system, I wouldn't mind that happening, it'd just be a bit more work for me afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 10 64-bit.

Look at your [hidden](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/9168-hidden-files-folders-drives-show-windows-10-a.html) `hosts` file at `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`

Comment the activate.abobe.com entries.

[Change](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/141019-block-websites-using-hosts-file-windows.html) something that looks like:

`127.0.0.1 activate.adobe.com` to `#127.0.0.1 activate.adobe.com`

Bing search [adobe C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts](https://www.bing.com/search?q=adobe+C%3A%5CWindows%5CSystem32%5Cdrivers%5Cetc%5Chosts&pc=MOZI&form=MOZTSB)

Sample hosts file:

```
# Copyright (c) 1993-2009 Microsoft Corp.
#
# This is a sample HOSTS file used by Microsoft TCP/IP for Windows.
#
# This file contains the mappings of IP addresses to host names. Each
# entry should be kept on an individual line. The IP address should
# be placed in the first column followed by the corresponding host name.
# The IP address and the host name should be separated by at least one
# space.
#
# Additionally, comments (such as these) may be inserted on individual
# lines or following the machine name denoted by a '#' symbol.
#
# For example:
#
#      102.54.94.97     rhino.acme.com          # source server
#       38.25.63.10     x.acme.com              # x client host

# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.

#127.0.0.1 activate.adobe.com
```